# Can I use this pattern for optional parts of where clauses?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, prepared-statement

I have this chunk of code, pretty standard stuff. It takes some filters in a java object, and returns all records matching the filters:

```java
class MarkFilters {
   Integer idFilter;
   Integer userIDFilter;
   Integer claimIDFilter;
}

List<Integer> findMarksMatchingFilters(MarkFilters filters) {
    String sql = "select id from Mark where 1";

    // This has the values to substitute in for the ?'s in the SQL
    List<Object> parameters = new LinkedList<Object>();

    if (filters.idFilter != null) {
        sql += " and id = ?";
        parameters.add(filters.idFilter);
    }

    if (filters.userIDFilter != null) {
        sql += " and userID = ?";
        parameters.add(filters.userIDFilter);
    }

    if (filters.claimIDFilter != null) {
        sql += " and claimID = ?";
        parameters.add(filters.claimIDFilter);
    }

    return executeSQLWithParameters(sql, parameters);
}
```

I found a way that should do the same sort of thing:

```java
List<Integer> findMarksMatchingFilters(MarkFilters filters) {
    return executeSQLWithParameters(
            "select * from Mark " +
            "where (? = NULL or id = ?) " +
            "and (? = NULL or userID = ?) " +
            "and (? = NULL or claimID = ?) ",
        filters.idFilter, filters.idFilter,
        filters.userIDFilter, filters.userIDFilter,
        filters.claimIDFilter, filters.claimIDFilter);
}
```

So for example, if I feed in a *new MarkFilters(null, null, 3)*, the sql statement will be:

```sql
select * from Mark
where (NULL = NULL or id = NULL)
and (NULL = NULL or userID = NULL)
and (3 = NULL or claimID = 3)
```

which will theoretically be optimized to:

```sql
select * from Mark where claimID = 3;
```

My specific question: Will that optimization actually happen?

My broader question: Is this a good pattern to follow, or are there drawbacks I can't see?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No.  The expression `NULL = NULL` evaluates to false.

You want:

```
        "select * from Mark " +
        "where (? is NULL or id = ?) " +
        "and (? is NULL or userID = ?) " +
        "and (? is NULL or claimID = ?) ",
```

I would expect that MySQL evaluates constant expressions at compile time.  This would mean that the `where` clause is simplified before evaluation.  However, I cannot find a specific reference in the documentation that guarantees this.

Comment: Darn, was afraid of that. So I suppose the next step is just for me to try it out and see if they have similar runtimes.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer, but I just found a nice alternative to the two methods I suggested:

http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html#chooseWhenOtherwise